# cron is failing to run my AppleScript

Tags: applescript, cron

I have the following code in a text file (myfile.applescript):

```
#! /usr/bin/osascript
tell application "Google Chrome" to quit
```

I would like Chrome to shut down each night at 9:15PM, so I added the following cron task to crontab:

```
15 21 * * * ~/Desktop/myfile.applescript
```

Unfortunately, the script is not triggering. Any thoughts?

NOTE: I am aware I can use iCal to resolve this problem. However, I'd prefer to not clutter my calendar with a daily script-triggering event.

Answer (score 4):

*Cron* has be deprecated on modern versions of OS X. Apple's suggestion is to use [*launchd*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/Introduction.html) instead. You will find [Lingon](http://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/) to be a useful tool for creating launchd daemons.

If you would prefer to use iCal to launch the script, you can create a separate calendar for scripted event(s), and hide it from view. It will function, but your calendar view will not be cluttered.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the `~/Desktop/myfile.applescript` file is executable. You can only call a script by filename if it has the relevant execute bit.

Consider the following Terminal session:

```
$ ls -laFh sh.sh
-rw-rw-r--  1 jason  staff   278B Mar  2 10:18 sh.sh

$ ./sh.sh
-bash: ./sh.sh: Permission denied

$ chmod 764 sh.sh

$ ls -laFh sh.sh
-rwxrw-r--  1 jason  staff    32B Mar  7 09:40 sh.sh*

$ ./sh.sh 
Hello World!
```

Until I had execute permissions (denoted with an 'x' in either the 4th, 7th, or 10th slot of the permissions string), I could not run it.

You can override it by calling the file with it's particular interpreter:

```
$ chmod 664 sh.sh

$ ls -laFh sh.sh
-rw-rw-r--  1 jason  staff    32B Mar  7 09:40 sh.sh

$ ./sh.sh
-bash: ./sh.sh: Permission denied

$ sh sh.sh
Hello World!
```

Comment: I'm sorry about the terrible filename. It was a temporary file so I gave it a stupid filename. But "sh sh sh" all in a row is very absurd.

And for the record: I highly suggest using launchd, cron is easier but launchd is more complete. Apps like Lingon that jaberg referenced really do help to make a functional launchctl plist in a hurry.

Answer (score 2):

I discovered my original script worked. The problem had to do with my cron entry: it wasn't terminated with a carriage return. Once I did that, the applescript triggered properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in your script.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
/usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell application "Google Chrome" to quit'
```

Make sure it's `chmod +x` and test from CLI.